# Smart card client certificate doesn't get registered in Personal store on Win 2003 x64 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate, smartcard

I'm accessing a smart card from c# through the Windows Certificate Store. This works well on many systems. On one system however, it doesn't. The smart card certificate is not added to the Personal Certificates.

We need it to be in the certificate store in order to access it from C#, like this:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certs =
    store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName,
    issuerName, false);
```

Details of the system:

- OS: Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 SP2

  The used CSP is [SafeSign Identity Client v3.0.11](http://www.aeteurope.nl/aet/aet-europe/_www/en/pub/products/safesign.cfm).

  The system is accessed through a Citrix ICA connection, Citrix Presentation Server 4.5.

What works:

- Accessing the card through a diagnostic tool provided by the smart card reader ([an OMNIKEY 3121](http://omnikey.aaitg.com/index.php?id=69))
- Viewing the personal certificates in Internet Explorer 7 (Tools > Internet options > Content > Certificates
- Basically everything else we tried with the card, except for...

What doesn't work:

- The personal certificates are not copied to the Personal Certificate Store (which can be checked with certmgr.msc)

My guess is that forwarding the smart card through Citrix works ok, because we can access it in almost all ways, but the CSP doesn't do its work correctly. Getting support for the CSP is not easy however, hence this question. And what I find strange is that the certificate is accessible through IE7, which shows that they are available in some kind of Windows store.

Any ideas on where to look further are welcome. Is there maybe a different way to access the smart card certificates like IE does?

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this issue turned out to be an incompatibility of the SafeSign Identity Client with 64-bit Windows. Official support will be added in a later version, I've been told fall 2009.